# Optional function parameter in tuple after variadic

Tags: typescript, types, tuples, variadic-functions, optional-parameters

I'm stuck with this simple problem:

```js
declare function Foo<T extends string[]>(...s: [...T, number?]): void;

Foo("");
/* error: Argument of type '""' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | undefined'.(2345) */

Foo(1); // ok

Foo("", 1); // ok
```

Why the first function call do not work while the last tuple element is optional?
I tried to solve this also with signature overload but no success either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why the current version doesn't work correctly. It will actually allow you to pass in an empty string, as long as you don't rely on inference:

```
Foo<[""]>("");
```

But that's obviously a bit cumbersome, so I understand why it may not be desirable

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwDEccAeAFXhAA8MRVgBneBjGLVAcwG0BdAPgAUAOhEMAXPC4ihZADTxUyALYAjEDAD8PAJQSAbjizAA3AFgAUBaKkuAIlv8B97WcvnrAgIwuLV4k9t5b1cgA)

The following type may work for you; it works for the cases you provided, and i havn't found any where it misbehaves:

```
declare function Foo<T extends string[]>(...s: [...T] | [...T, number]): void;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwDEccAeAFXhAA8MRVgBneBjGLVAcwG0BdAPgAUAOhEMAXPC4ihZHvAA+k6WQA08VMgC2AIxAweASgkA3HFmABuALAAoW0RwCARE4PW7NhwICMb2-eJnJzVfdyA)

Comment: Well it solves part of the problem (my bad, I didn't explained my extended need).
In case of "tail" parameter, `T` isn't strongly typed anymore:
```typescript
declare function Foo<T extends string[]>(...s: [...T] | [...T, number]): [...T];

Foo(""); // return type: [""]
Foo("", 3); // return type: string[]
```

Comment: Found it! Can be solved with signature overloads [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200924#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwDEccAeAFXhAA8MRVgBneBjGLVAcwG0BdAPgAUAOhEMAXPC4ihZHgEoJZANwAoUJFgIU6bHkLFylGnUbNW7bv2GiJUkWQA08VMgC2AIxAx5i1euhwSGiYuPhEpBTUtPRMLGycvILS4pLSsvAAPqn2Ti4eXj7wyioq4QIAROVySvAA9LXwcBjIMPgYAJ4ADiC2lTylxBXlTuW0LFU19Y0gza3wHd29w-CjIOP9ZZUjYxjLAMzVdQ1NLW1dPZJbKzvlPEA)
Thank you for you help @nicholas-tower !